# Chemical reactions and solutions of a constrained optimisation problem

Tags: optimization

I have to find a solution for this problem: given $N$ materials of density $\rho_k$, find the mixture of them giving a compound of density $\rho$. From a mathematical point of view, we have to find $q_k$ and $\rho_k$ for which:
$$\rho=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^Nq_k\rho_k}{\sum_{k=1}^Nq_k}$$
with $\rho$ given.
The constrains are: $\sum_{k=1}^Nq_k=Q$,$\forall k\le N$ $q_k\gt 0$.
I suppose there are infinite solutions for this problem. How to find one of them? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\rho=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^Nq_k\rho_k}{\sum_{k=1}^Nq_k}$? Otherwise, $\rho$ always equals $1$.

Comment: @Wolf: Just an error. I corrected it. Thnks

Comment: You might find your answer here if you are ok with a numerical solutation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365723/find-positive-solutions-to-underdetermined-linear-system-of-equations 
(just multiply your equation with $Q$).